# pexpect.run can not run a long command

Tags: python, pexpect

I am using `pexpect.run` to execute a command. See below:

```
cmd = "grep -L killed /dir/dumps/*MAC-66.log"
output = pexpect.run(cmd)
```

When I run this, `output` equals to:

```
grep: /dir/dumps/*MAC-66.log: No such file or directory
```

But when I run the same command in my shell, it works, everytime. I don't see the problem. Any help is appreciated! Does **pexpect.run** require the command to be split in some fancy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell is interpreting the glob, pexpect is not.  You could either use python's `glob.glob()` function to evaluate the glob yourself, or run it through your shell, for example:

```
cmd = "bash -c 'grep -L killed /dir/dumps/*MAC-66.log'"
```

Also, if all you're after is output of this command, you ought to check out the `subprocess` module.

Comment: That is current, I just read that pexpect does not handle wild characters.